# Proof of converge of alternating sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is an alternating sequence and that $\{|a_n-a_{n-1}|\}$ is a decreasing sequence converging to $0$. If $a_1 \neq a_2$, show that the sequence converges to some number between $a_1$ and $a_2$. (You may assume $a_1 < a_2$) Preferably an "epsilon-style proof" using the definition of convergence.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What theorems do you know about convergent sequences?

Comment: This is part of my introductory analysis course, so we covered Cauchy sequences and the basic definition of convergence.

Comment: What can you say about $a_3$ compared to $a_1$, and $a_4$ compared to $a_2$? (And similarly for all higher odd- and even-numbered terms) Do you know the theorem that any decreasing sequence that is bounded below (i.e., all terms are greater than or equal to some number $M$) must have a limit that's no less than $M$? (That's called the monotone covergence theorem).

Comment: Every odd term of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ would be negative? While all the even terms would be positive?

We haven't talked about that theorem yet, I don't see how it would be useful though.. It is obvious that the second sequence is bounded from below as it converges to 0.

Comment: Yeah...the odd terms are all negative, but can you tell me whether $a_3$ is less than or more than $a_1$? You might need to use the triangle inequality to answer that. And then you're on your own, because I'm going to sleep. (I also suspect that the question is mis-stated. I'm guessing it should be "$| |a_n| - |a_{n-1}| | \to 0$" instead of what you've got; otherwise it's really easy.

Comment: For others thinking of answering: Surely the correct form of the problem begins "Suppose that $\{ (-1)^{n+1} a_n \}$ is an alternating sequence and ..." Otherwise, the limit of the sequence is definitely zero. (The even terms are all negative; the odds are all positive, and the distance between successive terms heads to zero...so the triangle inequality makes them all head to zero.)

Comment: @John: Hmm, good point. If $\{a_n\}$ is alternating, then the even terms are all nonnegative and the odd terms are all nonpositive (or vice versa), hence if the sequence converges, the even subsequence implies that the limit must be nonnegative and the odd subsequence implies that it must be nonpositive. Hence the limit is zero.

Comment: @Idan: Please edit the OP if the problem statement is incorrect. If my proof can be patched to handle the new statement, I'll adjust accordingly. I'll delete it for now to avoid confusion.

Comment: @bungo This is exactly the way the problem is stated. This is only the second week, so don't be surprised if the answer is obvious. However, I still need some more guidance, as I don't see why it is.

Comment: @Idan: OK, in that case I'll simplify my proof to reflect John's observation. (I'd let him post it as an answer, but it sounds like he's off to bed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_1 < a_2$ and $(a_n)$ is alternating, it follows that $a_n \geq 0$ if $n$ is even and $a_n \leq 0$ if $n$ is odd. Therefore, $a_n \geq a_{n-1}$ if $n$ is even, and $a_n \leq a_{n-1}$ if $n$ is odd. This means that
$$|a_{n} - a_{n-1}| = (-1)^n(a_n - a_{n-1})$$
for all $n$. Equivalently,
$$a_n - a_{n-1} = (-1)^n|a_{n} - a_{n-1}|$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}a_n - a_1 &= \sum_{k=2}^n (a_k - a_{k-1}) \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^k |a_k - a_{k-1}| \\
\end{align}$$
The right hand side is an alternating series, hence convergent, since $|a_k - a_{k-1}|$ decreases to zero. Therefore, the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k |a_k - a_{k-1}|$$
exists. Call the limit $L$.

Now, since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$, it follows that all subsequences must converge to $L$. In particular, the subsequence consisting of the even indices, $a_{2n} \rightarrow L$. But since $a_{2n} \geq 0$ for all $n$, it follows that $L \geq 0$.

Similarly, the subsequence consisting of the odd indices, $a_{2n+1} \rightarrow L$. Since $a_{2n+1} \leq 0$ for all $n$, it follows that $L \leq 0$.

We conclude that $L = 0$.

---

Here is an alternative, even simpler proof. Since $a_1 < a_2$ and $(a_n)$ is alternating, we observe that:

- if $n$ is even, then $a_n - a_{n-1} \geq a_n \geq 0$
- If $n$ is odd, then $a_n - a_{n-1} \leq a_n \leq 0$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $|a_n - a_{n-1}| \rightarrow 0$, there is some $N$ such that $|a_n - a_{n-1}| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. If $n > N$, we have two cases:

**Case 1** $n$ is even

Then 
$$|a_n| = a_n \leq a_{n} - a_{n-1} = |a_{n} - a_{n-1}| < \epsilon$$

**case 2** $n$ is odd

Then 
$$|a_n| = -a_n \leq -(a_n - a_{n-1}) = |a_n - a_{n-1}| < \epsilon$$

So in either case, we have $|a_n| < \epsilon$ whenever $n >N$. We conclude that $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Note that we didn't even need the hypothesis that $|a_n - a_{n-1}|$ is decreasing. We just need it to converge to zero.

Comment: @Idan: Here is a simplified proof which highlights that the limit must be zero.

Comment: Thank you. This proof makes sense, however, is there an alternative way to go about proving this, using the definition convergence? (for all e>0, for some N....) @bungo

Comment: @Idan: Updated with an alternative, even simpler proof.